# How to connect nextjs app to graphql studio

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm trying to figure out how to open the apollo studio for my next js app.

When I run the local host, I get a message that says:

> Server started at http://localhost:5555/graphql

When I click that link, I get a page that says:

> GET query missing.

I'm trying to find a way to get to the apollo studio explorer.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking (or maybe for myself the next time I forget), the address: http://localhost:5555/graphql gets inserted in the sandbox address bar, that you find at the url: https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer. It won't work if you put the local host address in the url bar

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and have managed to solve it by connecting to apollo studio as a deployed graph (not using the sandbox) but running locally.

Firstly I followed this tutorial https://master--apollo-docs-index.netlify.app/docs/tutorial/production/ which does not use NextJS but it does connect a react app to the apollo studio sandbox then by section 5 it connects the deployed graph to apollo studio. Unfortunately section 5 is quite outdated so i will try to fill in the blanks and get you up and running.

- After you have set up an account in apollo studio add a new graph (+ New Graph button). Use whatever architecture you like but I tried this using 'supergraph'.
- On the next page ('Publish your schema using Federation') I used the 'schema document' tab and pipeline: 'Federation 2 Supergraph'.This generates the 2 of the 3 env keys you need to add to your local env file and feed it into your app. keys as follows:

1. APOLLO_KEY - this starts 'service:' and ends before the space, it is a single line about 50 characters long.
2. APOLLO_GRAPH_REF - this can be found at the end of the line below the APOLLO_KEY. it is a single word with a '@' symbol in the middle.
3. APOLLO_SCHEMA_REPORTING=true - written as shown here.

Do not close the 'Publish your schema using Federation' page/ re-open it if you have closed it as it will indicate that you have successful connected the graph when you run the app locally after the next step.

Start the app locally using the CLI and in the browser request a page that queries the apollo server.

Watch the CLI as the page is served and you should see the comment 'Apollo usage reporting starting!', also the 'Publish your schema using Federation' page should confirm the graph has been connected. Now you can use all the features of the sandbox as well as monitoring etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Next.js doesn't allow you to connect to Apollo Studio is because Next.js does not allow CORS by default in api handlers.
Apollo Studio tries to send a request from its own domain and it's blocked by Next.js default setup.

Let's assume you have your graphql/Apollo server in your NextJs app at `/api/graphql` path. When you navigate to that path (from your local) by using `http://localhost:3000/api/graphql` it will show you the welcome page and allow you to access Apollo Sandbox.

Once you enter the Apollo Sandbox in the bottom right corner it will display this message:
[image]

When you run the diagnose problem on your local you'll see the following message:

```
$ npx diagnose-endpoint@1.1.0 --endpoint=http://localhost:3000/api/graphql
Diagnosing http://localhost:3000/api/graphql
⚠️  OPTIONS response is missing header 'access-control-allow-methods: POST'
⚠️  POST response missing 'access-control-allow-origin' header.
If using cookie-based authentication, the following headers are required from your endpoint: 
    access-control-allow-origin: https://studio.apollographql.com
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
Otherwise, a wildcard value would work:
    access-control-allow-origin: *
( Interested in previewing a local tunnel to bypass CORS requirements? Please let us know at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScUCi3PdMerraiy6GpD-QiC_9KEKVHr4oDL5Vef5fIvzqqQWg/viewform )
```

The solution for the problem looks like this:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import Cors from "cors";
import { server } from "../../apollo";

// Initializing the cors middleware
// You can read here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options
const cors = Cors({
  methods: ["POST"],
});

// Helper method to wait for a middleware to execute before continuing
// And to throw an error when an error happens in a middleware
function runMiddleware(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  fn: Function
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result: any) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result);
      }

      return resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const startServer = server.start();

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  // Run cors middleware (to allow Apollo Studio access)
  await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);
  // run apollo server
  await startServer;
  await server.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" })(req, res);
}
```

It combines using the Apollo server and [this CORS example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-cors/pages/api/cors.ts)

the import:

```js
import { server } from "../../apollo"
```

from the example above is the apollo server that looks like this:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { typeDefs } from "./schema";
import { resolvers } from "./resolvers";

export const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
```

You can also use alternative options like [embedding sandbox into your app](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/studio/explorer/sandbox/#embedding-sandbox) but I'm finding the above solution a bit easier for my current needs so hope it helps you as well.